# sqlplus ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: authentication

on my windows 10 system every time I attempt to login I see the following error.

ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

During the install process I was not asked to create any users. I do seem to recall that I was asked to enter 'Oracle_1' as the admin password but I was not asked to enter an admin userid. I could not login with that id.

I was able to start a sqlplus session by executing "sqlplus /nolog". However, once in the session I really could not do anything, even a help command failed because I was not connected to a database.

On windows 10 how do I create a user that will enable me to successfully login and manipulate database tables ?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse on a Tomcat server, the config file is under Overview>Open Launch Configuration> Arguments Tab> VM arguments. Make sure the keys for -Ddb.user and -Ddb.password are correct. Also check the information in c:\users\\config\customProperties\startup\application.properties. Perhaps someone more experienced may chime in based on your current set-up.